# print value from XML respond

Tags: php

I'm working with web-services. I'm sending request and getting xml as a respond.
This is what I'm sending:

```
$s = new soapclient($conDetails['url'],array('wsdl'));
$params = new stdClass;
$paramsStr = '
            <GetPackItinerary UserID="'.$conDetails['UsrId'].'" SessionID="'.$conDetails['Session'].'" >
                <root>
                    <ItinId>'.$_GET['int'].'</ItinId>
                </root>
            </GetPackItinerary>
            ';
$params->xmlRequest = $paramsStr;

$result = $s->__call("SubmitXmlString",array($params));
```

if I print my resualt its look like that:

```
<GetPackItinerary Cnt="1">
    <int id="39">
        <header>
            <ItinId>39</ItinId>
            <Name>text for tour</Name>
            <Class>STD</Class>
            <Days>10</Days>
            <Text/>
            <Include>text for tour</Include>
            <NotInclude>text for tour</NotInclude>
            <Url>http://www.geotours.co.il</Url>
            <Status>OK</Status>
        </header>
        <day id="1">
            <ItinId>39</ItinId>
            <Destination/>
            <Day>1</Day>
            <Meal/>
            <Header>text for day 1</Header>
            <Text>some text</Text>
            <Include>some text</Include>
            <NotInclude/>
        </day>
        <day id="2">
            <ItinId>39</ItinId>
            <Destination/>
            <Day>2</Day>
            <Meal/>
            <Header>text for day 2</Header>
            <Text>some text 2</Text>
            <Include>some text 2</Include>
            <NotInclude/>
        </day>
    </int>
</GetPackItinerary>
```

My question is - what exactly do I get back from the WS? is it XML? obeject?
and - how do I print some value, for instant - the tag "name" in the "header" tag (text for tour) ?

Comment: It looks like XML and you'll need to use `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML` with the response

Comment: what gives to you this code: `echo gettype($result);` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - the word "object"

Answer (score 0):

It seems 'XML' to me. You could use SimpleXML to access the elements of the XML. Here's a way :-

```
<?php
//generate a file from **$result** and store it in your directory.
//save it as myfile.xml, which would be handled by simplexml_load_file
$fileHandler = simplexml_load_file("myfile.xml");
echo $fileHandler->GetPackItinerary->int->header->Name;

//outputs :- text for tour
?>
```

Comment: Do i have to save it in file?

Comment: @roi, yep, that;s preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard `DOMDocument` it is quite easy to navigate through the various nodes once you undersand some basics, but the following ought to give you the general idea.

```
$strxml='<GetPackItinerary Cnt="1">
            <int id="39">
                <header>
                    <ItinId>39</ItinId>
                    <Name>text for tour</Name>
                    <Class>STD</Class>
                    <Days>10</Days>
                    <Text/>
                    <Include>text for tour</Include>
                    <NotInclude>text for tour</NotInclude>
                    <Url>http://www.geotours.co.il</Url>
                    <Status>OK</Status>
                </header>
                <day id="1">
                    <ItinId>39</ItinId>
                    <Destination/>
                    <Day>1</Day>
                    <Meal/>
                    <Header>text for day 1</Header>
                    <Text>some text</Text>
                    <Include>some text</Include>
                    <NotInclude/>
                </day>
                <day id="2">
                    <ItinId>39</ItinId>
                    <Destination/>
                    <Day>2</Day>
                    <Meal/>
                    <Header>text for day 2</Header>
                    <Text>some text 2</Text>
                    <Include>some text 2</Include>
                    <NotInclude/>
                </day>
            </int>
        </GetPackItinerary>';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );

$root=$dom->getElementsByTagName('GetPackItinerary')->item(0);
$header=$dom->getElementsByTagName('header')->item(0);
$days=$dom->getElementsByTagName('day');

$tour=$header->childNodes->item(3);

echo $tour->tagName.': '.$tour->nodeValue.BR;/* Name: text for tour */

foreach( $days as $node ){/* 1,3,5,7,9 etc ~ even numbers are textNodes! */
    echo $node->childNodes->item(9)->tagName.': '.$node->childNodes->item(9)->nodeValue.BR;
}
```